# No base point implies globally generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $L$ be a line bundle (or more generally any sheaf) on $X$. Obviously the condition 'globally generated' implies 'base point free'. Is the converse always true?

---

**Edit**

Base point free means for any $x\in X$ we can find a global section $s$ of $L$ such that $s_x=0$ (or $s_x\notin m_x$?).

Globally generated means there exists a surjection of sheaves $\mathcal O_X^{\oplus I}\to L$.

And I didn't clarify the assumptions because I want to know about in how general this is true. For example, is this true for $X$ is a scheme and $L$ any sheaf? If not, what condition should be added?

Comment: Could you please provide your definitions of "globally generated" and "base point free"? I have always thought of these two concepts as the same thing!

Comment: Also, can you clarify your context and assumptions?  What is $X$ (a scheme? a variety over a field?)?  What kind of "sheaf" are you considering (quaiscoherent?)?

Comment: @KennyWong I added the definitions.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah that is because I want to know the general statement. You can add any condition you want :)

Comment: @Akatsuki  Are you sure that is what "base point free" means? My definition is as follows. First, observe that for any $x \in X$, $L_x \cong \mathcal O_x$ (because $L$ is locally free). Then I would say that $x$ is not a base point iff there exists a global section $x$ of $L$ such that $s_x \notin \mathfrak m_x \subset \mathcal O_x$, where $\mathfrak m _x$ is the maximal ideal in $\mathcal O_x$.

Comment: @KennyWong Oh, yes, I think you your definition looks more likely to be true in general... I always deal with the case over a field.

Comment: I think the real confusion is that for Akatsuki's definition to be the right one, $s_x$ should denote the image of $s$ in the fiber at $x$, rather than in the stalk at $x$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I agree.

Comment: @Akatsuki Anyway, once you have a global section $s$ of $L$ such that $s_x \notin \mathfrak m_x \subset \mathcal O_x$, you know that $s_x$ is a unit in $\mathcal O_x$, which means that the stalk $\mathcal O_x \cong L_x$ is generated by $s_x$  as an $\mathcal O_x$-module.

Comment: Why is it $s_x=0$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is true for line bundles.  If $L$ is basepoint-free, then for each $x\in X$ choose a global section $s(x)$ such that the image of $s(x)$ in the fiber at $x$ is nonzero, and consider the map of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus X}\to L$ that is given by $s(x)$ on the $x$ coordinate.  This map is then surjective on each stalk (since $L$ is a line bundle so each stalk is generated by any element whose image in the fiber is nonzero), and thus surjective.

It is not true for general sheaves.  For instance, let $M$ be your favorite sheaf that is not globally generated and let $L=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus M$.  Then $L$ is basepoint-free because $\mathcal{O}_X$ is, but is not globally generated because $M$ is not.  (The converse is also not true for general sheaves: for instance, the zero sheaf is globally generated, but is not basepoint-free!)